# Why area under curve (AUC) in ROC decreases when I use more variables?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, matlab, roc

My dataset has 400 observations of 100 features.  Each of the 400 observations belongs to 1 out of 2 classes.

I am training a neural network ([patternet(15)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ref/patternnet.html)) in MATLAB for classifying this dataset.
I don't use all the features at once, but first I use one feature (400x1), then I add a second one (400x2) and so on. At every step I calculate the AUC using [perfcurve](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/perfcurve.html).

Here is my problem:

The AUC is changing but it is not always getting larger with each additional input.
Shouldn't the AUC be increasing as I use more features to train the network? (I always use the same divisions through [divideind](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ref/divideind.html)).

All comments and help are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the ROC curve you produced, as well as the structure of your network. Better yet, you could post the code you used.

Comment: Maybe the first features are more discriminatives, and the last ones only add noise ! You could try to run a random forest and see which features are the most discriminatives between the categories

Comment: @bendaizer you were right, the first ones were the most discriminative! the features I had, had been pre-ordered based on the difference of their distribution between the categories.

Comment: @bogatron sorry for taking so much time to answer, I had changed projects for a few months. still it will be difficult to post all the ROC curves, because MATLAB gives me four ROC plots for every additional feature, so they would be about 400 plots

Comment: also, I don't know why, but I cannot upvote your comments...

Comment: If you want, I can post my comment as an answer and you can vote for it :)

Comment: @bendaizer. Please do. It was the right answer after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the first features are more discriminatives, and the last ones only add noise ! You could try to run a random forest and see which features are the most discriminatives between the categories